# Why does non-constant $f\in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(nP),X)$ mean that $f$ has a pole of order $n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Why does non-constant $f\in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(nP),X)$ mean that $f$ has a pole of order $n$? I have seen this used in the proof that for every point $P$ on $X$ there exists a non-constant rational function $f$ that is regular everywhere except for $P$.

By definition, if $f\in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(nP),X)$, then $(f)+nP\geq 0$, which implies that $v_P(f)\geq -n$. But this is not necessarily an equality, so why do we have such a pole? This inequality alone doesn't preclude the possibility that $v_P(f)$ is a positive number. What am I missing?

Comment: Your objection sounds correct to me.  I suspect this is addressed somewhere in the proof you're referring to, but it's hard to say without seeing the actual text of the proof.  Can you edit your question to add quotes?

Comment: For example, does the proof run through a statement of the form $\mathrm{dim} \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(nP),X) > \mathrm{dim} \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X((n-1)P),X)$?

Comment: Oh wait, I may have missed something--are you only concerned about the possibility that $v_P(f) \geq 0$?  In that case, $f$ would be a regular function.  What do you know about regular functions on $X$?  (Is $X$ projective?)

Comment: there is certainly an injection $\Gamma(\mathcal O_X((n-1)P),X)\hookrightarrow\Gamma(\mathcal O_X(nP),X)$, which should be a proper injection for $n$ large enough by some Riemann-Roch argument.

Comment: @RaviFernando For instance, in the comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007543/exercse-4-1-1-of-hartshorne-find-a-rational-function-on-a-curve-with-a-pole-at

Comment: @KentaS that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a complete curve. Then for all $n\ge1$ there is an injection $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))\hookrightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(nP))$, from the injection of sheaves $\mathcal O_X((n-1)P)\to\mathcal O_X(nP)$ together with the fact that $\Gamma(X,-)$ is left exact. Here $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))$ consists of functions $f$ that are regular away from $P$ and such that $v_P(f)\ge-(n-1)$. Thus, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(nP))\setminus \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))$ consists of the functions $f$ that are regular away from $P$ and such that $v_p(f)=n$ exactly.

Thus, to have a $f$ with pole of order exactly $n$ at $P$ we need $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))\hookrightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(nP))$ to be a proper injection. One criteria that assures this is $n\ge 2g$. Indeed, by [Riemann-Roch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) we have $\dim\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(nP))=n-g+1$ and $\dim\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))=n-g$.

---

Note that as a special case, when $X=\mathbb P^1$, Riemann-Roch tells us $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(P))$ is $2$-dimensional and $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)=\mathbb C$, the space of constant functions, is $1$-dimensinoal. Thus any non-constant function in $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(P))$ has a pole of order exactly $1$, which may be what you were referring to.

Comment: How can I see that $\mathcal{O}_X((n-1)P)\to\mathcal{O}_X(nP)$ is an injection?

Comment: @Kenta S - when you write $\mathcal{O}_X(nP)$ this usually means an "invertible sheaf" and when you write $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X(nP))$ this means the global sections of an invertible sheaf - such a global section $s$ is not a function but it gives rise to its "divisor of zeros". For an irreducible curve one usually defines for any divisor $D$ the vector sub-space $L(D) \subseteq K(X)$ of the quotient field $K(X)$. This is a vector space consisting of rational functions on $X$ with "prescribed zeros and poles".

Comment: @ponchan I guess it is easier to see directly that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X((n-1)P))\subset\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X(nP))\subset K(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

You'll note that in my [linked comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007543/exercse-4-1-1-of-hartshorne-find-a-rational-function-on-a-curve-with-a-pole-at#comment6205368_3007543), I never say that there is a function $\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}} f \in \L(nP)$ with a pole of order exactly $n$, only that there is a *nonconstant* $f \in \L(nP)$ if $n \geq g + 1$. For $n \geq g+1$ we have
$$
\ell(nP) \geq 1 - g + n \geq 2 \, .
$$
The constant functions contribute a $1$-dimensional subspace, so the fact that $\dim \L(nP) \geq 2$ means there is some nonconstant function $f \in \L(nP)$.

I think the part you might be missing is that every nonconstant rational function $h$ on a projective curve $X$ has a pole somewhere. Considering $h$ as a morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$, since $X$ is irreducible and projective (actually, [proper suffices](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6)) then the image of $h$ is irreducible and closed. For any point $P$ in the image of $h$, we have the containments of irreducible closed sets
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\img}{img}
\{P\} \subsetneq \img(h) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^1
$$
and since $h$ is nonconstant, the first containment is strict. Since $\mathbb{P}^1$ has dimension $1$, this means that we must have $\img(h) = \mathbb{P}^1$. Thus $h$ is surjective, so in particular takes on the value $\infty$.

So now we've established that the nonconstant $f \in \L(nP)$ has a pole somewhere, and the fact that $\operatorname{div}(f) + nP \geq 0$ means that the only possibility is at $P$. Thus $f$ has a pole at $P$ and is regular elsewhere.

Indeed, as you say, $f \in \L(nP)$ implies $v_P(f) \geq -n$, which simply means that $f$ has a pole of order *at most* $n$ at $P$. There are curves $X$ and values of $n$ and $P$ such that there is no function with a pole of order exactly $n$ at $P$ and no other poles: such $n$ are called [Weierstrass gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point).